# Can/Should NSSheets be used for text field input?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

I have a Cocoa app underway and I'm thinking about how to get people to enter and/or change text fields.

The main window is an `NSTableView`, and there are subordinate tables, where people will add/choose selections.

I was thinking that for both adding a new record, or selecting from a set, an `NSSheet` could work quite nicely. But I don't know if this is appropriate.

Finally, are there better ways to do this? Examples?

Comment: But you can directly add on your tableview without using NSSheet. Why using sheet??

Comment: Hi Hussain, ok, when I add a record, if I use a sheet, I can get the user to enter more than one field. I also want to use a sheet as a selection tool.. what do you think?

Comment: Ok so you mean to say when user click on the button one sheet should come and then if user wants to enter then he can enter if doesn't then just cancel the sheet right??

Comment: exactly.. and, if this is ok, I'd like to follow up on my question yesterday on how to do it.. All has changed with Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as you wanted to add new record on the basis of user selection in the sheet. If really its requirement then it is fine, there is no any issue on using sheet.

But only problem is performance issue will be there. Because user has to first click on button and then sheet will appear and then enter into textfield and then again click on the ok button or cancel button so it seems like delaying in your application.